# Keras: Constrained dictionary search with CTC decode

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to constrain the CTC decoding to a specific (external) dictionary in Keras with a the tensorflow backend. In the [tensorflow documentation for Keras' ctc_decode](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/ctc_decode), it is written that when `greedy=False` a dictionary will be used. Here is the [documentation for  tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_beam_search_decoder), which will be called by this option as far as I understand.

Since there is no way to pass an external dictionary or language model (to constrain the search), I assume that with `greedy=False` it creates its own dictionary from the training data. Is this correct? Is there a way to constrain the search to a specific (external) dictionary?

Comment: The `ctc_code` implementation in Tensorflow's backend is this one: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/ctc_decode which is different from `tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder`

Comment: @GPhilo Exactly, that's the first link in the post. However, if using the option `greedy=False`, following the code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/0478e07ccab79db931061329484d6e97c4a6e072/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3986) we will finally reach `tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder`, as far as I understand.

Comment: You're right, I got confused by the different import (the script has `from tensorflow.python.ops import ctc_ops as ctc`) and I thought it called directly the underlying C++ code wrapper, but I see now that `tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder` is implemented in that python file.

Comment: It looks like there's no dictionary functionality fully implemented as of this date.  See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12356 for info on how to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check this out!